# How set min and max time in TimePicker (WP 8.1)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is some way to narrow displayed hours in TimePicker?
I didn't find any appropriate properties (hard to believe,there is no such a possibility),also tried using data context:

```
class TimePickerDataSource
{

    public List<TimeSpan> Hours { get; set; }

    public TimePickerDataSource()
    {
        Hours = new List<TimeSpan>{new TimeSpan(9,0,0),new TimeSpan(10,0,0)};
    }
}
```

and later in MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
      StartTimePicker.DataContext = new TimePickerDataSource();
```

but i don't know how to bind it in my xaml (if it is possible):

```
<Grid x:Name="My Grid">
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DisplayedName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="163" FontSize="20" />
    <TimePicker x:Name="StartTimePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock">
    </TimePicker>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# code you could try this.

```
        this.dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = new System.DateTime(2015, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new System.DateTime(1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```